# LazReport doesn't work on second machine

Tags: debugging, lazarus

I have two computers - Ubuntu 12.04 + Lazarus. Let's call them A and B.

I develop a program on A. It works fine.
I run the same program on B using Lazarus and it works fine.

Then I make a compiled program (binary) on A and try it on B. Now the problem starts.

Everything works fine except that none of the reports (LazReport) appear. There's no error. Just no response. The program continues without a crash but just no response. How is this possible?

Clues:

1. On machine A and B, I installed the software (Lazarus) as the default admin user.
2. On machine B, I have another user account but this is a standard user.
3. On machine B, I installed LazReport component on Lazarus using the standard user account. So I suspect a permissions issue.
4. Then I removed the LazReport component on Lazarus from machine B and reinstalled it a second time. But this time I ran it as admin like this `gksu -u ADMIN -w startlazarus` but still no change.

Please advice how I may solve this problem.

My restriction:
I must be able to do this using the standard account and not ADMIN. Is this even possible?

Thanks!

EDIT: here's the output of `ldd`:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76f3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76c3000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb758f000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xb756d000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb7105000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb7056000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb7007000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb6f0e000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xb6f0a000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xb6f05000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xb6ebb000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xb6df0000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xb6dd0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb6dca000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6c20000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76f4000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb6bff000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xb6aa8000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6a7c000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xb6a6e000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb6a68000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xb6a3c000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb6a08000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb69f6000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xb69eb000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0xb69e7000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xb69d7000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xb69ce000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0xb69c3000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xb69be000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xb69ba000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb69b3000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb6977000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb696e000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xb68d5000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb683b000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb6811000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xb680d000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xb6803000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb67ec000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb67e8000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb67e1000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xb67c2000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xb67aa000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb677f000)
```

They appear IDENTICAL on machines A and B except that the hex number within brackets is different. Apart from that, it's the same line to line.

EDIT: More info - new findings...

I opened a terminal. Then ran Nautilus. Then I run my binary and when trying the report, I got this error in the terminal:

> [WARNING] SetAlphaBlend called without handle for
>   frProgressForm(TfrProgressForm)

I have no clue but I believe this is the bug. I have no form like the one mentioned either.

Comment: I'm confused by "I develop a program on A. It works fine. I run the same program on B using Lazarus and it works fine." - how are you running it - your next statement implies that transferring a binary fails.

Comment: What does the output of `ldd` show for the binary when you run it on A and B?

Comment: First, a big thank you for showing me `ldd`. I was searching for a way to identify dependencies. Second, WOW! That's a big list in the output but honestly, I can't make much sense out of it. It onl lists dependencies - no errors of any sort. I guess we're looking for a mismatch. I'll paste the results shortly.

Comment: @SB. I've posted the ldd output and commented as well. It's the same.

Comment: @SB. In response to your first comment, I am able to run on both machines WITH the IDE and without (i.e., using the binary). BUT on the second machine the reporting doesn't work. That's my issue.

Comment: Maybe the report needs some extra dll to laod

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Thanks for your input. But I thought we don't use DLLs on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes and no, they are called .so, but they have roughly the same function, and more importantly, like DLLs they can either be linked statically (visible by ldd), or loaded dynamically by loadlibrary/dlsym

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, as I discovered much later, the reports didn't work outside of the development folder although the rest of the application did.

The solution was to simply copy the report files (.lrf) and put it into the destination folder that contained the binary.